# Vite Hot Reload not working instead its reloading entire page (React.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, vite

i just migrated my CRA to vite successfully using the link `https://dev.to/nilanth/use-vite-for-react-apps-instead-of-cra-3pkg`, but whenever i do little change the entire application is reloading in browser, i tried  upgrading & downgrading my vite version but still i can't solve the issue

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dummy",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "framer-motion": "^7.5.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "react-router": "^6.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1",
    "reactflow": "^11.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "1.1.1",
    "vite": "2.7.0"
  },
}
```

**Folder structure**

```
├── src
│   ├── App.css
│   ├── App.jsx
│   ├── App.test.js
│   ├── Components
│   │   └── Modal
│   │       └── PopModal.jsx
│   ├── Index.jsx
│   ├── Layout
│   │   └── Layout.jsx
│   ├── Pages
│   │   ├── Custom
│   │   │   ├── Chart.jsx
│   │   │   ├── Custom.jsx
│   │   │   └── chartCustom.css
│   │   ├── Domain
│   │   │   └── Domain.jsx
│   │   ├── Github
│   │   │   └── Github.jsx
│   │   ├── Login
│   │   │   └── Github.jsx
│   │   └── Settings
│   │       └── Settings.jsx
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── logo.png
│   ├── logo.svg
│   ├── logo1.png
│   ├── setupTests.js
│   ├── store
│   │   ├── axiosClient.js
│   │   ├── client.js
│   │   ├── const.js
│   │   └── reducer.js
│   └── utils
│       ├── Routeutils.jsx
│       └── token.js
```